# How to delete records in Einstein Analytics Dataset

Tags: einstein-analytics, tableau-crm, crm-analytics

I am finding it very hard to find the ways for deleting the records in CRMA dataset. It is totally unclear and there is no easy OOTB function for deleting the records.. Should i create a new dataset everytime if there is some data mismatch issues ?

Whenever i click on the dataset it takes me to a page and gives me the option to delete entire dataaset. But my requirement is deleting records based on some criteria.

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use a recipe/dataflow and add filter node to filter out unwanted rows; and then use the API name of existing dataset in the output node to overwrite the data without unwanted rows.